# Validation of MVC application depending on dropdownlist options

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, dropdown

In my MVC application I have a DDL. When I select a particular item from the DDL, say 'Active', two textboxes will be appeared and if we select a different item from the DDL a another DDL will appear on the screen.
Both the cases textboxes and the DDL are mandatory but depending on different options of the DDL.

Any help will be thankfully accepted.

Thanks

Partha

Comment: Consider using a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[RequiredIf]` or similar conditional validation attribute that will give both client and server side validation

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about client side validation then probably the easiest way would be adding `required` attribute to the dependent DDL and the texboxes. In order to disable the validation when those texboxes/DDL are hidden simply add `disabled` attribute to them once you hide then and remove the attirbute when you show them.

For server side validation you may take a look at [FluentValidation](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation) library, which allows [conditional validation](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/wiki/d.-Configuring-a-Validator#user-content-specifying-a-condition-with-whenunless)